# Enable a workflow for Experience Fragments

Tags: adobe, aem

We have a integration from AEM to Adobe Target through Adobe IO.

Current Implementation

1). Author is responsible to login to AEM author and create or update experience fragment in author
2). Above Author will export the same Experience Fragment to Adobe Target clicking on Export to Adobe Target

We have requirement like below

1). Author is responsible to login to AEM author and create or update experience fragment in author
2). Author will trigger the workflow, Authoriser should review the experience fragment and complete the workflow
3). Experience Fragment should export to Adobe Target internally after Authoriser completes the workflow.

Can you pleaes suggest me how to handle this scenario.

Thanks In Advance.

Thanks & Regards
Veera

I haven't tried anything for new requirement, I need your support for this requirement.

Comment: Can you provide more details, like what have you tried? AEM Workflows receive a payload which can be a Experience Fragment, a page, or asset, for example.